# Laravel - Notification Mail ShouldQueue does't work

Tags: php, laravel, queue, laravel-7

**I would like to send email notifications using the queue.**

*I have created the queue table and tracked all the documentation related to this topic but the notifications are sent without going through the queue.*

**In my controller :**

```
Notification::send(User::role('team')->get(), new NewExchangeToCollaboratorNotification($user, $exchange, $firstMessage));
```

**And my notification code is :**

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Setting;

class NewExchangeToCollaboratorNotification extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable;

    protected $user; protected $exchange; protected $exchangeMessage; protected $replyToAddress;

    public function __construct($user, $exchange, $exchangeMessage)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->exchange = $exchange;
        $this->exchangeMessage = $exchangeMessage;
        $this->replyToAddress = Setting::get('MAIL_REPLY_TO_ADDRESS', env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS'));
    }

    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)->view(
            'emails.exchanges.new',
            [
                'user' => $this->user,
                'exchangeMessage' => $this->exchangeMessage,
                'exchange' => $this->exchange
            ]
        )   ->subject('New exchange: ' .  $this->exchange->title)
            ->from(env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS'))
            ->replyTo($this->replyToAddress);
    }
}
```

**Are the notifications queueable ? Is there something I'm doing wrong ?** 
Thank you for your answers :)

EDIT : 
Add delay does not work too.

```
$when = now()->addMinutes(10);
Notification::send(User::role('team')->get(), (new NewExchangeToCollaboratorNotification($user, $exchange, $firstMessage))->delay($when));
```

EDIT 2 : 
No failed job

Comment: Have you tried running a queue worker? php artisan queue:work

Comment: Yeah @Adnan but does not work always. I also try to add delay when i send it but that doens 't work :         
$when = now()->addMinutes(10);
Notification::send(User::role('team')->get(), (new NewExchangeToCollaboratorNotification($user, $exchange, $firstMessage))->delay($when));

Comment: Did you check failed jobs via `php artisan queue:failed`?

Comment: There is none @Daniel :(

Comment: Your .env is QUEUE_CONNECTION=database, right?

Comment: Done, that's work well now @Mondini I thought I did

Comment: I'm glad. I've added a answer aswell. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your .env is: 
`QUEUE_CONNECTION=database`